# Docker: Mongodb container error execute "listdatabases" command

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, docker-container

I am trying to connect to mongodb container from **robomongo** that installed on host machine but i got:

```
Cannot connect to the MongoDB at 192.168.1.6:27018.
Error:
Failed to execute "listdatabases" command
```

I know this is about `ip binding`.This my docker compose file:

```
version: '3'
services :
  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.2.0
    command: --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB 1.5 --bind_ip_all
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
    restart:
      always
    container_name:
      mongo-docker
```

So i added `--bind_ip_all` argument but i still got this error?

```
groot@wsl: /mnt/c/Users/Groot
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES       
9359012fc83d        mongo:4.2.0         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        0.0.0.0:27018->27017/tcp   mongo-docker
```

Answer (score 0):

It is merely an issue with cached container .`docker-compose up --force-recreate` would solve the issue .

I had validated your compose file . Nothing wrong in that